# Obtener fecha de creación de una imagen en una url con php

Tags: php

¿Cómo podría saber la fecha de creación o modificación de una imagen que se encuentra en una url?
Ejemplo: tengo la url de esta imagen:

> https://newrelic.com/assets/pages/apm/php/php-elephant-logo-bd4f9d83be8c8563248fe4793f90bae7.png

y quiero saber su fecha de creación, y había estado utilizando la función `filectime()` pero siempre me devuelve 31/12/1969 18:00

**Gracias**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener la última fecha de modificación de la imagen podrías obtener las cabeceras de la url en cuestión, dentro de éstas encontraras `Last-Modified` que es la ultima fecha de modificación de la imagen. Para esto debes usar la función [get_headers()](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.get-headers.php)

En código seria algo así:

```
<?php
$nombre_archivo = 'https://newrelic.com/assets/pages/apm/php/php-elephant-logo-bd4f9d83be8c8563248fe4793f90bae7.png';
$headerArray = array();
$headerArray = get_headers($nombre_archivo, 1);

/***Imprimir todos los valores del arreglo de cabeceras

echo "<PRE>";
var_dump($headerArray);
echo "</PRE>";

*/

echo "Ultima fecha de modificacion: ".$headerArray["Last-Modified"];
//Este ultimo echo muestra: Ultima fecha de modificacion: Mon, 13 Mar 2017 21:49:40 GMT
?>
```

**EDIT**

Para cambiar el formato de la fecha puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
echo date("d/m/Y G:i",strtotime($headerArray["Last-Modified"]));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me has salvado, si quisiera camiar el formato de la fecha que me está regresando.. con un date_format() se podría?
si no es mucha molestia

Comment: De nada, si te sirvió la respuesta no olvides marcarla como solución a tu problema. Y claro si se puede formatear la fecha, en que formato quieres tener la fecha?

Comment: no había visto como hacerlo pero creo que ya la marqué, en cuanto al formato sería este: 
"d/m/Y g:i"

Comment: @MichelleVitePacheco acabo de editar la respuesta con tu duda, espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias